# ObjC valueForKey doesn't work for NSNumber nor UDTs

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, objective-c-runtime

I am trying to deep-parse my own collection of objects into an NSDictionary (for JSON).

I have a base object class, which ***All*** of my models extend, and this baseobject in turn extends NSObject:

```
@interface BaseObj : NSObject <DICTMaker>
    - (NSMutableDictionary *) toDICT;
@end
```

In the method, I use objc-runtime to get a list of properties. Any property which I can get a reference to using `[self valueForKey:]`, I go ahead and insert into my dictionary the name and value of the property.

However, what I've noticed thus far is that `NSNumber`s and user defined classes are not added to the dictionary! My parser most assuredly identifies them, because I have it spitting out everything to the log; but `[self valueForKey:]` returns `nil` on all `NSNumbers` and user defined objects.

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)toDICT {
    NSMutableDictionary *props = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    unsigned int outCount, i;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &outCount);
    for (i = 0; i < outCount; i++) {
        objc_property_t property = properties[i];

        // Both of these work, I promise:
        NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(property)];
        NSString *propertyType = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:getPropertyType(property)];

        NSLog( @"%@ of Type: %@", propertyName, propertyType );
        id propertyValue = [self valueForKey:propertyName];
        if ( [ propertyValue respondsToSelector:@selector(toDICT:) ] )
            [ props setObject:[propertyValue toDICT] forKey:propertyName ];
        else if ( propertyValue )
            [ props setObject:propertyValue forKey:propertyName ];
        else
            NSLog( @"Unable to get ref to: %@", propertyName );
    }
    free(properties);
    return props;
}
```

Here is a sample object I threw at the creator:

```
@interface UserRegistrationLocation : BaseObj {
    NSString *address, *street, *street_2, *city;
    NSNumber *addr_state, *addr_zip;
}

@interface UserRegistrationContact : BaseObj {
    NSString *first_name, *last_name;
    NSString *p_phone_area, *p_phone_first_3, *p_phone_last_4;
    NSString *s_phone_area, *s_phone_first_3, *s_phone_last_4;
}

@interface UserRegistration : BaseObj {
    NSString *email, *password, *password_confirm;
    NSNumber *referral;

    UserRegistrationContact *primary, *secondary;
    UserRegistrationLocation *address;
}

NSMutableDictionary *mydict = [myUserRegistration toDICT];
```

The resulting dictionary only contained entries for email, password, and password_confirm:

```
[11012:f803] Unable to get ref to: referral
[11012:f803] Unable to get ref to: primary
[11012:f803] Unable to get ref to: secondary
[11012:f803] Unable to get ref to: address
[11012:f803] {"user":{"password":"haxme123","password_confirm":"haxme123","email":"my@email.com"}}
```

Any assistance please =} !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I understood the problem wrong, but are your referral, primary and so not simply null?
If they are not in the keyvalue store, you would get an exception.
You else part is only called, if the property is found in the keyvalue store but has a nil assigned. At least from your example code, one cannot decide, if the values are set.

If I reduce your example to the code below, I get the following output
    test with Value: (null)
    Unable to get ref to: test
    aNumber with Value: 5

test is null and will give your message "unable...". aNumber is correct. If I change test to some text, the "unable..." part vanishes. The additional member variable _noProp which is not a property does not occur here, as copyPropertyList copies only properties.

```
@interface TestValueForKey : NSObject {
     NSString* _test;
     NSString* _noProp;
     NSNumber* _aNumber;
}

@property (retain) NSString* test;
@property (retain) NSNumber* aNumber;

-(void)myTest;

@implementation TestValueForKey

@synthesize test = _test;
@synthesize aNumber = _aNumber;

-(id)init
{
    if( (self = [super init]) != nil) {
       _test = nil;
       _aNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:5];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)myTest
{
    NSMutableDictionary *props = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    unsigned int outCount, i;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &outCount);
    for( i = 0; i < outCount; i++) {
       objc_property_t property = properties[i];

       // Both of these work, I promise:
       NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(property)];

      id propertyValue = [self valueForKey:propertyName];
      NSLog( @"%@ with Value: %@", propertyName, propertyValue );
      if ( propertyValue )
          [ props setObject:propertyValue forKey:propertyName ];
      else
          NSLog( @"Unable to get ref to: %@", propertyName );
  }
  free(properties);
}
@end
```

Comment: How embarrassing, my inner objects were being assigned data.. but the classes themselves weren't being properly initialized! -10programmer pnts

Answer (score 2):

You've only declared ivars for the values, not properties. `class_copyPropertyList` requires `@property` declarations. You could use the ivar accessing functions such as `class_getInstanceVariable`.

However, I think this approach is trying to be a bit too clever. I would implement a method that returns an array of keys to serialize, eg, `-(NSArray *)keysForJSONSerialization`. This would reveal intent more clearly and will allow you to prevent the serialzation of certain properties (which I suspect you'll want at some point).

Comment: I assumed the property declarations just weren't shown - since the names do turn up in the logs, they must exist in the array? +1 for the second paragraph, though

Comment: As jrtuton suggested, the corresponding `@property` and `@synthesize` declarations were in fact present, though removed from the listing above for simplification. But still no money